# What version of Maven is heroku using?

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm attempting to use a Maven plugin that requires version 3.0+ :

http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/index.html

But I receive this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.6:add-source (scala-compile-first) on project spring-hibernate-template: The plugin net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.1.6 requires Maven version 3.0.4 -> [Help 1]
```

Is Heroku using an older version of Maven? If so can I update it for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Heroku Java buildpack, it's using Maven 3.0.3:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/blob/master/bin/compile#L56

You can double-check which buildpack you're using.

Answer (score 1):

## Update as of February 2016

Currently [this buildpack uses Maven 3.3.9](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

## Original answer

As of September 2014 it's using [`Maven 3.0.5`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java/commit/52c3e981b7c5a67e49dc4a49fe1dcf5fbe2b48b5) so original problem here would be resolved now.

If you encounter too low Maven version problem you have to find/make your own [custom buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-custom-buildpack) with newer Maven.

I made a custom buildpack with `Maven 3.1.1` you can use with this command:

`heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/grzegorz-dubicki/heroku-buildpack-java.git#5e6b4a3`

(This is a specific commit that works. I can't promise that HEAD of my repo will always work.
Of course you should fork it and use your own repo's address not to depend on my repo in the long run.)

Please publish your custom buildpack with other Maven versions here - especially if you manage to do that for `Maven 3.2.x` and if it turns out not to be trivial!